# Symfony2 Assetic: How to display uploaded image which path is stored in database?

Tags: image, symfony, twig, assets

When I have image stored in my bundle dir structure displaying image is easy with Assetic as from documentation:

```
{% image '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg'
    filter='jpegoptim' output='/images/example.jpg'
%}
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example"/>
{% endimage %}
```

but how can I use assetic for my uploaded images? below my getWebPath returns path relative to web dir for example: "/uploads/images/image.jpg". Maybe this solution is ok and there is no need to use assetic? I think that using it for some filtering like above jpegoptim could be useful

```
<img src="{{app.request.basepath}}/{{ entity.getWebPath }}">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ app.request.host ~ '/' ~ entity.getWebPath }}" />
```

Comment: I got the same done in second snippet code, question is how to do this with Assetic.

Comment: in your getWebPath returns path relative to web dir for example: "/uploads/images/image.jpg" u can do this only and it work perfectly `<img src="{{ entity.getWebPath }}" />`, the browser will add automatically the host name :)

Comment: i tried so and the path is then relative to my actions and parameters routes f.ex: app.php/action/param1/param2/uploads/images/image.jpg and as result got 404 for that image

Comment: that's because `entity.getWebPath` doses not containt `/` at the beginning, so try this `<img src="{{ '/' ~ entity.getWebPath }}" />`

Comment: anohter method u can use this: `<img src="{{ asset(entity.getWebPath) }}" />`

Comment: I will accept for your effort as the only one interested on my question.thx

Answer (score 0):

you can store them on the automaticcaly generated web direectory 'uploads/files/' using getUploadRootDir(),getAbsolutePath()... and call them using
src="{{ asset('uploads/files/'~entity.path) }}"